# Android: How to start an Activity from an alert dialog

Tags: android, events, dialog, android-activity, click

I need to start an activity when the user chooses an item in an alert dialog. How do I get the context to pass to the intent constructor in the following code...

```
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                Intent i = new Intent(<WHAT DO I PUT HERE?>, <new activity>.class);    
                startActivity(i);

      }

});
```

Is it the use of the inner class?? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can retrieve the context you have passed to `AlertDialog.Builder` with `getBaseContext()`.
See the doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getBaseContext()).

So this should work:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), <new activity>.class);    
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent("some.thing.activity"); 
startActivity(i);
```

//in the brackets you can add the activity path, ie: the package name 
//eg: za.ac.cut.Activity