# How to start an activity from an AlertDialog?

Tags: android

I created an `AlertDialog` :

```
public class ConfirmChoixDownloadDialogView extends AlertDialog {

    private Activity activity; // this activity shows this Dialog

    private View contenu, titleBar;

    private final int OUI = DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE;
    private final int NON = DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE;
    private final int NEUTRE = DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL;

    public static final int requestCode = 100;

    private int btnClicked = NEUTRE;

    private AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> indirectTask;

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    public ConfirmChoixDownloadDialogView(Context context, LayoutInflater inflater) {
        super(context, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK);
        contenu = inflater.inflate(R.layout.msg_dialog, null);
        ((TextView)contenu.findViewById(R.id.msgText)).setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.questionChargementWebVersMobile));
        titleBar = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_title, null);
        ((ImageView)titleBar.findViewById(R.id.icone)).setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_about));
        ((TextView)titleBar.findViewById(R.id.titre)).setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.titreConfirmMsgBox));
        setCustomTitle(titleBar);
        setView(contenu, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, context.getResources().getString(R.string.button_oui), new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                btnClicked = OUI;
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, context.getResources().getString(R.string.button_non), new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                btnClicked = NON;
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        setOnDismissListener(dismissListener);
    }
    public void afficher(Activity act, AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> tacheIndirecte) {
        activity = act;
        indirectTask = tacheIndirecte;
        show();
    }
    private OnDismissListener dismissListener = new OnDismissListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {

            if (dialog instanceof ConfirmChoixDownloadDialogView) {

                if (btnClicked == OUI) {

                    indirectTask.execute("commune.txt",
                                         "parcelles.txt",
                                         "rues.txt",
                                         "batiments.txt",
                                         "appartements.txt",
                                         "occupants_appartement.txt",
                                         "categories_activite.txt",
                                         "natures_activite.txt",
                                         "activites_dans_appart.txt",
                                         "contribuables.txt");

                }

                else if (btnClicked == NON) {


                    Intent i = new Intent(activity, SelectionQuartierActivity.class);
                    activity.startActivity(i); // it makes app crash

                }

            }

        }

    };

}
```

As you can see I want to start an `activity` in the case when the `BUTTON_NEGATIVE` of the `Dialog` is clicked. But it crash ! So how to start the `activity` in this case ?

Comment: Can you post the crash log?

Comment: I cannot because I run the app on a tablet and its driver is unfound by the computer.

Comment: You cannot use the emulator? or add https://try.crashlytics.com/ to the application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to start an Activity from an alert dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691414/android-how-to-start-an-activity-from-an-alert-dialog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , I found a tip to start the `activity` from the `activity` which opened the `Dialog` by implementing the `onWindowFocusChanged` method of the `activity` and setting a `public static` variable of the `activity` inside the `OnDismissListener` of the `Dialog` !

Answer (score 1):

```
showDialog(this, "", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivty.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case maybe try using the context of the AlertDialog instead of the Activity calling it like this:

`context.startActivity(i);` instead of `activity.startActivity(i)`