# How to start an activity if a button pressed on dialog box

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I used below code to show a dialog box and I tried to go to home page if positive button clicked. but seems like IDE can't resolve `startActivity` method. what is the correct way to start an activity inside `onClick` event?

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Blocked!")
                .setMessage("This application is restricted by administrator")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        Intent startHomescreen=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        startHomescreen.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                        startHomescreen.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(startHomescreen);
                    }
                })       .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();
```

Comment: use context.startActivity()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do

```
context.startActivity(startHomescreen);
```

Refer some others posts

1. [Android: How to start an Activity from an alert dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691414/android-how-to-start-an-activity-from-an-alert-dialog?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

```
context.startActivity(startHomescreen);
```

It will work my friend !